# What is the main difference in Code OSS and VSC?

Tags: linux, ide, manjaro

Code OSS seems to be very similar or the exact same to VSC. I was then told to install the *bin* version of VSC in the Arch wiki.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code OSS is open source repository of microsoft's visual studio code project which is a distribution of the Code - OSS repository with Microsoft specific customizations, including additional source code and extensions, released under a traditional Microsoft product license.

visit [Code-OSS's official Wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code) for detailed information.

Comment: I don't think there should be any problem while using .NET Framework in Code OSS.